# Origin of 'bog-standard'

Tags: etymology, british-english, phrase-origin

Today, while reading an interview of Camilla Pang in *The Guardian* of 28 Nov [2020](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2020/nov/28/camilla-pang-you-have-to-acknowledge-the-hilarity-of-what-it-is-to-be-human), I found this in the article:

> Deviations from that – whether through being a woman, or being neurodivergent or because of your race – hit a subconscious bias where some people think: “OK, how reliable is this person?”, and wait for something to go wrong because they’re not the *bog-standard* fit. [emphasis added]

While I have for a long time been aware of the term 'bog-standard' and what I surmised from context was its meaning, "down-to-earth, basic standard", I became curious about the origin — and also about what I felt was a slightly off-kilter use by Pang, but that's neither here nor there. I "had recourse to" [*OED*](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/251255?redirectedFrom=bog-standard&) (to paraphrase Boswell about philosophy), and soon learned that the term was considered (a) recent and (b) of "uncertain origin". *OED* also confirmed my surmise about the meaning, although not my association of the term with 'down-to-earth'. The first attestation given was from an ad in the [April, 1962](https://www.motorsportmagazine.com/archive/article/april-1962/67/for-sale-continued-5) issue of [*Motor Sport*](https://www.motorsportmagazine.com/?s=bog&type=issue_content):

> Bog standard Sprite, 1959, two owners.

The *OED* story about the term was similar to the story at [*The Phrase Finder*](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/bog-standard.html), a source of "unequal reliability", and other sources summoned by invoking internet search engine demons ([DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=canonical&q=origin+of+bog-standard&atb=v192-1&ia=web)) repeated much the same story. (None of the sources, by the way, corroborated my association of the term with 'down-to-earth'.)

The existing stories are summed up in the *OED* entry, which is new as of the 3rd Edition, March 2002:

> **Etymology:** Origin uncertain; perhaps an alteration of *box standard* n. (although this is first attested later [1983]), after *bog* n.<sup>4</sup> [a "toilet, a lavatory; the room or outhouse containing this"].
> Differing theories of the origin of *bog-standard* have been proposed, but none proven. An immediate association with *bog* n.<sup>1</sup> seems unlikely on semantic grounds. The most commonly held view is that the transition from box to bog resulted from a mishearing or misunderstanding of *box standard* n.
>
> Others have suggested a derivation < *bog-wheel*, former Cambridge slang for a bicycle, though ultimately also related to *bog* n.<sup>4</sup>....

Can anybody (who reads this and is willing, etc. etc. etc.) add anything substantial to the story of the 'bog-standard'?

Comment: Also read [BBC](https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/radio/specials/1728_uptodate/page25.shtml), [Wikitionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/bog-standard) and [WorldWideWords](https://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-bog1.htm#:~:text=Bog-standard%20is%20a%20well,a%20dismissive%20or%20derogatory%20way.&text=It's%20a%20shortened%20form%20of,an%20even%20older%20term%2C%20boggard.)

Comment: Also GDoS suggests only OED assumption: https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/gi6mdcq

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/321172/j-olivers-usage-of-the-word-bog/321186#321186

Comment: I like the technical origin and I have always assumed it referred to [bog ore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bog_iron). Bog standard would mean what the bloomeries produced as a primary smelt, ie, unalloyed and nonspec - kind of like ordering "crusher run" from a gravel pit or "sweep the floor" at the diner.

Comment: It is likely that there was a _deliberate_ transition from box-standard to bog-standard by people wanting to allude to 'bog' as in 'toilet'.

Comment: Just a guess based on my recollections but in the UK during the 1960s, 70s and early 80s didn't every *standard toilet* in most working class households  look identical to one another?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Maybe; good idea, but I couldn't find support in the history of the British toilet articles (of which it seems there are many).

Comment: It appears to be of relatively recent (1970s) origin -- https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bog+standard&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3

Comment: And the term appears to have first gained popularity with regard to automobiles.

Comment: @HotLicks, early to mid 1960s in the automotive (rally) subculture. They tacked bog- onto a lot of things. There might be an origin in that. See *Motor Sport*.

Comment: @user66974, sure, for now; progress, not finality, is what I'm hoping for, given my own failure to achieve the latter. My latest research (after examining the motor sport bog- subculture, which still seems promising) has touched on two points: (1) 'bog-wheel', frequently mentioned as a possible origin, aside from the fanciful notion that it was adopted as a result of the wheel resembling a hole in a toilet seat, turns out to have been a wheel designed for moving timber carriages more easily; (2) the reputed existence of a *Bog Standard* newspaper in historical Cumberland, around The Bog.

Comment: As standards go, "bog-standard" sounds like a pretty crappy one. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Bog-standard being related to toilets/lavatories at some point is probably because of the term [bog-house](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/boghouse). In your quote from OED, it says that the use of box-standard in the meaning of "ordinary" first appeared in 1983, thus making this theory not as possible.

I have also found that 1983 quote, just for fun. This quote was said by the inventor Sir Cline Sinclair in an interview with magazine *Computerworld*, February 1983:

> Luckily, we cannot foresee the day when a computer becomes just a standard box. There will be box-standard machines along the road, but we do not simply have to make those.

Some have also speculated that BOG is an acronym for British or German. This is plausible as during the world wars, the British and German technology was so good, that everyone had to use them, which made British or German the "ordinary". Thus, the [term BoG standard](https://podcasts.apple.com/pl/podcast/bog-standard-british-german-tech-talks/id1550844259) was coined. Some also think that BoG is for the British or German engineering during the [Victorian era](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-bog1.htm). I can't find any real documents before 1970 using these terms, so this theory may be a little sketchy.

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer, but can't be sure of its truthfulness though.

'bog-standard' is 'beyond-the-pale' in the sense that its outside the domain of civilised / advanced 'England', because geographically speaking, beyond the pale there were lots of bogs! In this sense bog-standard is simple or inferior, but also sufficient and rugged.

Its possible that the usage was in slang/non-standard English for a long time before being attested to.

Comment: Comments deleted. It may, however, be worthwhile to cite "beyond the pale". (I reckon that *pale* is simply a fence, the current *paling*; and used figuratively it simply separates "Us" from "Them".)

Comment: I am attracted to the answer. In many slang dictionaries, "bog standard" is followed by "bog trotter" (derogatory slang for an Irish person.) The difficulty comes with the date, 1962: As reference to the simple and inferior nature of things that came from the bog has been around for over 400 years, it is a little late in arriving.

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer that I was told in the mid 1970's when I started work and acronyms were starting to be popular.
BOG standard meant British or German standard. Which at the time was as good a standard as you could get. At the time Britain was still a strong engineering/ manufacturing base. Japan was up and coming, while China and Hong Kong were the cheap and simple. How times have changed.
Like lots of things like gay, the word has become corrupted to have a totally different meaning.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to confirm this, but I heard the origin of the phrase when I was looking for the origin of a rude phrase.

In the 1930s, Meccano had two versions of its toys: box-standard and box-deluxe.

It doesn't take any imagination to see how box-standard could get changed to bog-standard, to mean run-of-the-mill.

Similarly, box-deluxe became bog-deluxe which was instantly transformed by the Cockney laws of spoonerisms to Dog-beluxe. There was one more stage in that phrase's journey, producing a phrase meaning "best quality", but I won't mention it here.

https://www.grammar-monster.com/sayings_proverbs/bog_standard.htm